# prevent extremely slow performance of codeigniter application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Currently i am developing an student information system and i am using premium bootstrap template for my application development. But the problem is now my web app being extremely slow; at first i thought that all of the different css files and js are the main reason for the issue; so i have magnify both css and js than put it into the one single file.

which makes my application 10 second faster than previous one. But the problem is now my apps gets 30 sec to load a single page. Also i have put all of the models in the single file which is 69KB in size. and i have done same for my controller which is 178KB in size.

I have also tried to implement cache on my controller which make my app just load in 10 sec but the problem is when i do CRUD operation then the changed result is not showing insistently. So my question is how can i make the application load time much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many reasons how your application is slow.

1. Use Autoload only whenever required.
2. Keep the config files in cofig directory.
3. Filter all input before adding them to DB.
4. Use less of core PHP code if there is an CI alternative.
5. Use helper or library for frequently used functions.

Also,
- Enable GZIP compression if you are on a online server.
- make fewer HTTP requests.
- Config files there are alot of you can disable to speed up.

Although this is just my view. There are many ways to speed up and many reasons slowing your application. It is all onhe your study on how you have coded your application.

**hope this helps a little. :)**

Comment: Thank You for your kind information